# How do I do nested interpolation in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat that requires nested interpolation to be evaluated. Here is an example:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in ['1', '2', '3']">
    should evaluate to {{ i }}: {{ (i>0) && ( {{ i }} ) || false }}
</div>
```

This throughs a $parse error. The problem I figure is that Angular can't perform nested evaluation operations, or support nested interpolation.

Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: Why do you have them nested? It doesn't make sense. You already have 'i' available to you. Also, I'm very confused with what this statement is supposed to do.

Comment: @ZackArgyle the snippet is just an example code snippet. It's a ternary statement if you weren't aware.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when trying to create a dynamic table component. With the following code I'm able to display any table from the database on the front end without having to define anything thanks to nested interpolation.
You just need to use square brackets for the nested interpolation.
E.G: {{row[[col.column_name]]}}

```
<table id="dynamicTable" class="table table-hover" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of Columns">{{col.column_name}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of Table">
            <td *ngFor="let col of Columns">{{row[[col.column_name]]}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps! (Working with Angular 7)

Comment: This is not for AngularJS as the title says

Comment: True. But while searching for a solution myself (5 years after this question was asked) I kept coming across this post without an answer. I was searching for a solution for Angular 7 but as I'm sure you are aware Angular JS questions will keep clouding the search results. So when I did find a solution I thought it might be helpful to others to post this with a note saying it is working in Angular 7. Not JS. Not expecting it to be accepted as the answer but it might help someone in the same position I was.

Comment: The problem begins where you mix two different languages in one question. You should've created a new question involving angular 7 and post your solution. THAT is how this magical place (for most of us) woks. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @AndyOR what's funny is here I am, in the exact same position as you, but now in Angular 11. Thank you! My line ended up being ```placeholder="{{(param.value == null || param.value ==='NULL' || param.value === '') ? ('Select '+[[param.parameterDisplayName]]): ([[param.value]]) }}"```

Comment: @CollinFox, very happy to hear that I was able to help in some way. The languages are so similar that I was hoping by posting this answer here, I could at least nudge someone in the right direction. Thanks for the comment and recognition. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

It's giving you parse error because you can't nest {{}}..

{{ code }} basically tells angular that whatever is inside {{ }} (*code* in my case) is JavaScript, and js doesn't understand {{ }} syntax. This is why second `{{ i }}` is causing a problem.

You might also want to look at ngRepeat docs - there are some special properties, like $index, that you can use.. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: So the answer is, it is absolutely not possible to nest ``{{ }}`` within ``{{ }}`` ? There's no alternate syntax?

Comment: The answer is you don't _need_ to nest.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what's this  `{{ i }}: {{ (i>0) && ( {{ i }} ) || false }}` statement is about , also you cannot have nested `{{}}` in angular js.

Are you trying to make

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HMjnV/8/)**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="i in ['0','1', '2', '3']">
       {{ i>0 ? true: false }}
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it is also a Ternary. The above issue still stands with your example:
  
``<div ng-repeat="i in ['0','1', '2', '3']">
 {{ i>0 ? {{ i }}: false }}
</div>``

Answer (score 0):

The result of what's in the {{}} will be printed - no need to nest:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in ['0','1', '2', '3']"> {{ i > 0 ?  i : false }} </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Collin's code,

> `placeholder="{{(param.value == null || param.value ==='NULL' || param.value === '') ? ('Select '+[[param.parameterDisplayName]]): ([[param.value]]) }}"`

you can use `[[inner condition]]` to nest. This works !